# jOOQ Spring Boot compiling query but not inserting into db

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jooq

I am currently trying to use jOOQ in my springboot project to insert certain data given by user from a html form into a MySQL db. This is my MainController responsible for getting data from the form and executing the query through a VisitorRepository: I'm using both add and insertVisitor methods but neither of them are working.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final VisitorRepository visitorRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MainController (VisitorRepository visitorRepository) {
        this.visitorRepository = visitorRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String main() {
        return "main";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Phonenum firstSubmit(Phonenum phonenum){
        System.out.println(phonenum.getPhonenumber());
        visitorRepository.insertVisitor(phonenum.getPhonenumber(),"now", phonenum.getName());
        return visitorRepository.add(phonenum);
    }
}
```

VisitorRepository interface:

```
    public interface VisitorRepository {

    public Phonenum add(Phonenum visitor);

    public List<Phonenum> findAll();

    public void  insertVisitor(String phoneNumber, String submitTime, String name);
    }
```

And the repository implementation:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class VisitorRepo implements VisitorRepository{


private final DSLContext dslContext;


public VisitorRepo(DSLContext dslContext){
    this.dslContext = dslContext;
}


public void insertVisitor(String phoneNumber, String submitTime, String name){
    this.dslContext
            .insertInto(Phonenum.PHONENUM)
            .columns(Phonenum.PHONENUM.PHONENUMBER, Phonenum.PHONENUM.SUBMITTIME, Phonenum.PHONENUM.NAME)
            .values(phoneNumber, submitTime, name);

}


public com.demo.visitorlog.model.Phonenum add(com.demo.visitorlog.model.Phonenum visitor) {
    this.dslContext
            .insertInto(Phonenum.PHONENUM)
            .columns(Phonenum.PHONENUM.PHONENUMBER, Phonenum.PHONENUM.SUBMITTIME, Phonenum.PHONENUM.NAME)
            .values(visitor.getPhonenumber(), String.valueOf("submit time"), visitor.getName());
    System.out.println("ran");
    return visitor;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to setup the config class but here is what I have:

```
@Configuration
public class mainConfig{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider
                (new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
        return jooqConfiguration;
    }
```

So I get the `System.out.println()` after the post request but when I look into my db there isn't anything inserted. Am I missing something? Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Spring Security automatically enabling csrf Protection which I had to manual disable in the Security Config class using:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `.execute()` to execute the query

```
this.dslContext
            .insertInto(Phonenum.PHONENUM)
            .columns(Phonenum.PHONENUM.PHONENUMBER, Phonenum.PHONENUM.SUBMITTIME, Phonenum.PHONENUM.NAME)
            .values(visitor.getPhonenumber(), String.valueOf("submit time"), visitor.getName())
            .execute();
```

Comment: I called .execute() but it still didn't add the data into the db. Instead this logged: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [116] milliseconds.

Comment: I also get a WhiteLabel page error after submitting the form with type=Forbidden, status=403

Comment: @ph-quiett  Use `@Autowired` on `DSLContext`

Comment: `@Autowired` isn't needed in case of a single constructor with arguments.

Comment: Also you are getting 403 Forbidden. Did you configure any security on endpoints

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez what do you mean by security on endpoints?

Comment: That is explained in the Spring documenation .

Comment: Security configuration can cause 403 forbidden. This is authentication error

Comment: @M.Deinum got [it](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) starting from `4.3` . Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I don't have any security endpoints setup. So I don't need to `@Autowired` on `DSLContext` right

Comment: I'm also getting 403 forbidden for `/admin` login routes (even though authentication is correct)